# IMAP Email Error

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, imap, microsoft-outlook-2013

IMAP Outlook Error Message

I have some IMAP email accounts with some serious issues which neither I or my host GoDaddy can get their heads around.

In Outlook 2007, everything was fine, but since people have moved over to 2010 and 2013, they are being bombarded with the error message

> Your IMAP server wants to alert you to the following: Fatal error: Did NOT to connect to an internal server.: Cannot assign requested address

There are a large number of accounts now experiencing this when set-up with IMAP. The email accounts are are on different domains (different TLDs also) and are Setup on a range of machines and software systems. The error does not apear on 2007, but does outlook 2010 and 2013. The PCs with these accounts setup are across different Networks and ISPs some related, some totally unrelated. The only common denominator is Outlook and a GoDaddy server.

These accounts can SEND and RECEIVE emails fine - no problems here - but every 10-30 minutes an annoying popup windows error message from Outlook produced this message. While I agree with GoDaddy that these are technically "Working" unfortunately its not workable. We set-up another IMAP accounts on a different email server (US based this time) and the same error was produced.

I am now trying to figure out weather this is a problem linked to Outlook, or their mail servers? Does anybody recognise this error or is able to point me in the right direction?

What I have tried so far includes

- Re-setting up mail accounts and mail profiles
- Trying Outlook 2007 (no problems) and 2010,2013 (problems)
- Removing Firewalls and Anti-Virus
- Installing on a fresh windows 7 and office 2010 PC
- Installing on a fresh windows 7 and office 2013 PC
- Increasing time-out,
- Trying different ports that 143 and 25
- Trying different server addresses (imap.domain.com and imap.secureserver.net and imap.europe.secureserver.net - all of which are valid but makes no difference)
- Trying PCs on other ISPs and Network Locations etc...

and now I am stuck.

Comment: The message **IMAP server wants you to know** strongly indicates that the problem is on the server side.  Call Godaddy and keep complaining until they fix it.

Comment: What @Zoredache said. "IMAP server wants you to know" is how Outlook passes along error messages returned from the server, and "Fatal error: Did NOT to connect to an internal server.: Cannot assign requested address" appears to be a GoDaddy-specific problem. If GoDaddy keeps telling you "everything is fine" and won't take steps to fix it then you should be moving to a host that is not terrible.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback guys... I really appreciate it !

Comment: Just a quick comment, that using Port 993 with SSL and a Monster 10minute Outlook timeout, seems to eliminate the error all together, looks like an issue with 143, possibly a timeout issue...